# Biholomorphism between $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |(z)| < 1 \}$ and $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0 \}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find an explicit biholomorphism between $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}\mid |(z)| <1  \}$ and $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid\text{Im}(z) > 0 \}$.

I was thinking about the function $$f:\{z \in \mathbb{C} | |(z)| < 1 \}\to\{z \in \mathbb{C} | \text{Im}(z) > 0 \}$$ given by $f(z)=\frac{iz}{z-1}$ and its inverse $g(w)=\frac{w}{w-i}$. How can I demonstrate that they are holomorphic, with Cauchy-Riemann equations?

---

Comment: First express the real and imaginary parts of $f$ and $g$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, then differentiate and compare...

Comment: $g$ has a pole at $w = i$ and $\mathfrak I (i) = 1 \gt 0.$ Do you mean $|z|$ by $|(z)|\ $?

Comment: $f= \frac{y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}+i \frac{x^2-x+y^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$ and $g= \frac{x^2+y-1}{x^2+(y-1)^2}+i \frac{x}{x^2+(y-1)^2}$

Comment: with $|z|$ i mean the module of $z$ like a complex number

Comment: Your assignment might require you to verify the CR equations explicitly, but in general a faster way to do this is to use the fact that compositions, sums, products, and quotients (away from poles) of holomorphic functions are holomorphic. In particular, a rational function on a domain in $\mathbb{C}$ is automatically holomorphic if the domain contains no poles.

Comment: ok, thx, so the function that i gave it s correct right?